# Пытаюсь сделать проект на Unity, возникает ошибка при обращении к объекту списка list

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю проект по учёбе. По идее должен сохраняться набор характеристик персонажа в одном отдельном файле. В момент передачи переменной из одного файла в другой - возникает ошибка. Сообщает о том, что index должен быть неотрицательным либо меньше чем размер массива. Объясните глупому, что я сделал не так. (В С# я посредственно прохожу, ещё учусь).

По идее я в любом случае беру цифру из Dropdown.value от 0 до 4х. После чего присваиваю её переменной и с помощью функции передаю в другой файл. А там её не котируют как индекс.
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
(строка где происходит первое присваивание LoadChars.character[].exist = 1)

Честно пытался разобраться с помощью интернета, и других ответов, но не доходит.

Файл LoadChar

```
{
    private string filepath;
    public static int cellchar;
    public Dropdown CharacterCells;
    public static List<Stats> character = new List<Stats>(5){};
    public void Start()
    {
        cellchar = Convert.ToInt32(CharacterCells.value);
        ...
        }
    }
    static public int Givecell()
    {
        return cellchar;
    }
}

Файл CreateChar1

public class CreateChars1 : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    ...
    public Text text;
    public int createcell;
    public void CreateChar1()
    {
        createcell = LoadChars.Givecell();
        text.text = "00000";
        LoadChars.character[createcell].exist = 1;
        LoadChars.character[createcell].name = IName.text;
        LoadChars.character[createcell].nameplayer = INamePl.text;
...
```

Comment: просто выполните отладку и гляньте какой индекс на самом деле при обращении к элементу списка

Comment: @iKuzmichov, отладку выполнил, теперь сообщает, что Не удалось найти элемент "createcell" для "this"
https://imgur.com/ld3ic7I. Хотя вроде так как они стоят в static'е, то всё должно быть нормально...

Comment: @RusStrizh тогда нужно разобраться что такое модификатор "статик" и не пихать его куда попало :) Ну или же научится обращаться к статическим обьектам правильно. А то явно видно что ты не понимаешь ни что такое стати ни как с ним работать

Comment: @Andrew, подсказки такими тёмными намёками - так себе) Но спасибо, со статиками вроде разобрался... Но ошибка всё равно осталась, как не крути...

Comment: @RusStrizh ничего не разобрался ты. Иначе бы ты понял в чем ошибка. И именно в этом и есть смысл даного "темного намека" как ты выразился. Ты думаешь что ты понимаешь тему, а ты ее не понимаешь от слова "совсем". Вот прям ни на грамм. Иди разбираться дальше.

Comment: Кроме того у меня прямым текстом написано 2 решенияю: 1 - убрать модификатор статик с переменной; 2 - научиться обращаться к статическим переменным. Ты даже без гугления мог бы последовать п.1 и решить проблему.